# How can I achieve the layout like the image below?

Tags: html, css

The 'layout 1' is an layout for the desktop version. It should be like it when the pixel is above 992px:

[image]

I have created the layout as shown in pic but to provide space between the all the sections, I have used the `margin-right` property. The problem is that, when I give `margin-right` property in css, the 2nd section goes to next row and doesn't behave as an responsive. Without it, The website works fine and also behave as an responsive.

Comment: Use media queries in css. Align divs using float:left;

Comment: We discourage questions of the form "please see my repo <here>", as these tend to break or change. Would you put the relevant code into your question please? [Here it is](https://mohdyusuf963.github.io/hello-world/) for readers in the meantime.

Comment: Remember margins don't count as width. If you add 2% margin, width should be 46%.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use :

1. Bootstrap grid system . http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

   ```
           or
   ```
2. css3 flex box. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

These help get away with unnecessary float.